# Value of input in jQuery event returns undefine

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I've two separate js files. One of them, called `services`, where I define the input field and run some jQuery with it. The other file calls `services` and works with the returned value.

If I use the value within the function(in `services`), it returns the correct value. Otherwise, in my secound file, it does return undefined because it seems like, if I call the function, it does not wait until the `.change` event is triggered

Services.js

```
var service = {

    main: function() {
        console.log(service.input);
    },

    init: function( input ) {
        service.input = input;
    },

    getInputValue: function() {
        $('#' + service.input).change(function() {
            return $('#' + service.input).val();
        });
    }
};
```

OtherJsFile.js

```
$(function(){
    var inputField;

    service.init('inputId');
    inputField = service.getInputValue();

    //Should print the value of inputId
    //Instead it prints undefined
    console.log(inputField);
});
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You are not returning anything from `getInputValue()`, you are only returning something from the change handler (which doesn't do anything unless returning false). By default if there is no return value, JavaScript returns undefined - which is why `inputField = undefined`. You should probably change your function to `return $("#" + service.input).val();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This won't help me, I need this jQuery event

Comment: I think you really misunderstand what you're trying to do =|

Answer (score 0):

One problem is what you return inside the change handler only returns to the event handler function, not to the outer `getInputValue`. So nothing is being returned from `getInputValue()` ... and that's why you see undefined.

Next issue is the event hasn't occurred yet when you are trying to get that value.

To be honest I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: I try to reduce redundancy because I need that `.change` event more than just one time. And the value will used for some ajax requests

Comment: need that change handler to do what exactly? Perhaps you need an array of callbacks to pass into the change handler. Then loop through that array and call them all. Or use some custom events

Comment: My intention is to get the end value of the input field which can be filled in by a user. For instance: User types in "Hello World" I receive this value and can use it for my ajax post request. Whatsoever, its not my only input field. I've a few.

Comment: But you only need the value. Logic doesn't make sense adding a change event listener unless that event needs to trigger some ajax.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer. I'll try to fix this up.